# best way to replace the first occurrence of an item in an array

Tags: javascript

Is this the best way to replace the first occurrence of something?

```
my_list[my_list.indexOf(old_item)] = new_item
```

Note: If the item is not in the array, I don't want anything to happen. (No errors / broken array)

Comment: Seems as good as you can get to me. But you should check if `indexOf()` succeeds first.

Comment: It's perfect.
Negative indexes on arrays are hidden, ie they are hidden js data / values, they don't get iterated, they don't get exposed by JSON stringify, nor on array to string conversions, or an array to source, etc., and they don't alter the length value of the array - it's as if they're not there at all.  But they exist! e.g.: [array][-1] > will return the most recent data assigned to it. So your method is practically safe and the fastest available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not sure the item is in the list you should do:

```
var idx = my_list.indexOf(old_item)
if (idx !== -1) { my_list[idx] = new_item }
```

But else I think it's the best way to do it.

Setting a value at the index -1 won't raise an error, but will still modify the object as would setting a key in a generic js object:

```
var my_list = [1, 2, 3];
var old_item = 5;
var new_item = 10;
my_list[my_list.indexOf(old_item)] = new_item;
// my_list is [1, 2, 3, '-1': 10]
// my_list.length is still 3
// Object.keys(my_list) is [ '0', '1', '2', '-1' ]
```

So you probably don't want to do it.

Comment: Didn't he specifically say that he only wanted to replace the first *occurrencee in the list?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks, that was a typo! Meant the first matching index.

Comment: Will it raise an error if the index is `-1` and we try to replace something?

Comment: See my edit. It won't raise error, but seems to have surprising behavior

Comment: @Guig -what's the 'surprising' behavior?

Comment: I was stupidly not expecting `-1` to be considered as a traditional js object key and to be handled as an array would handle it in other languages (in most it would throw)

Comment: @Guig -we're talking JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really! There are a few ways you could do it -- one is the way you have, another is using the `search` method rather than `indexOf`, which is more versatile in that it can accept regex arguments. Note however that `search` is not supported in some older JS environments. There are also longer, worse ways, like using `filter`, or `splice`, but those definitely wouldn't work better.

The only suggestion I'd make is a conditional that checks whether old_item is still in the list -- `indexOf` returns `-1` if something is not in the list, and in that case, you'll be replacing a non-existent index.

Basically, I think you're fine -- it might not be the prettiest expression, but it's about as succinct as you can get in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not useful structures to search values. You may consider a set instead:

```
my_set.delete(old_item);
my_set.add(new_item);
```

Note that your code may not behave as expected if `old_item` does not appear in the array, then `indexOf` will return `-1`. Maybe use something like this:

```
var idx = my_list.indexOf(old_item);
if (idx >= 0) my_list[idx] = new_item;
else my_list.push(new_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` is definitely one of the best ways.  But you want to make sure `indexOf` was successful before using it:

```
var index = my_list.indexOf(old_item);

if (index !== -1) {
    my_list[index] = new_item;
}
```

Also you can use the `~` operator if you are into terse JavaScript:

```
var index = my_list.indexOf(old_item);

if (~index) {
    my_list[index] = new_item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution using `Array.prototype.indexOf` and `Array.prototype.splice` functions:

```js
var myList = [1,2,3,4,5], oldItem = 4, newItem = 7;
~(pos = myList.indexOf(oldItem)) && myList.splice(pos, 1, newItem);

console.log(myList);
```